# Visual Studio debug LUA scripts withing C++ Project

Tags: debugging, lua, lua-c++-connection

I am currently participating in an open source project, which uses Lua Scripts within a C++ Project in Microsoft Visual Studio. I am now trying to debug an issue which is happening within one of the LUA Scripts. I installed the following VS Extention https://github.com/WheretIB/LuaDkmDebugger. However VS Still does not stop at the Break Points. Attached you will find Screenshots of the Warnings and Indications I am currently having.
[image: Breakpoint during active Debugging]

[image: Extention Script List]

Is there any way to fix this or any external Tool I could use to debug these LUA Scripts?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score -1):

The code language that the Visual Studio supported is limited.

Take a look of this:

[Demos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/visual-studio-ide?view=vs-2022#get-started)

Visual Studio only support these languages:

[image]

Lua is not listed. And you can also know this when you install visual studio components via visual studio installer.

Please consider using visual studio code.